# Replacing hyphen, space and question mark with star

Tags: regex, coldfusion

I am trying to replace hyphen, space and question marks with `*` using a regular expression in ColdFusion. It looks like:

```
ReReplace( txt, "-?\s+\?*","*", "All" )
```

but it is not replacing the question mark at the end of string. Any help?

Comment: What is the string you test it against? Try replacing `\s+` with `\s*` and `\?*` to `\?+`: `"-?\s*\?+"`. Or use an alternation like `-?\s+\?*|-?\s*\?+$`

Comment: Can you please update your question to be more explicit with what you're wanting to match? Your narrative is unclear as to whether it's "any discrete occurrences of -, [space], or question mark", or the exact sequence "- ?", or "any number of any of those characters", etc. None ofthis is clear given the disconnect between your narrative and your example regex pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make your code more readable I'd write it like this:

```
<cfscript>
txt = "Hello! testing 1-2-3. How are you?";
foo = ReReplace(txt, "[- ?]","*", "All");
writeDump(foo);
</cfscript>
```

That will return:

```
Hello!*testing*1*2*3*How*are*you*
```

Characters in a range (the square brackets) don't need to be escaped, which makes it easier to read (to me anyway!). It's worth noting that `-` is a special character in a range, so I've put it as the first character.

If you did `[ -?]` the regular expression would match any character between the space  and `?` and return:

```
Hello**testing*******How*are*you*
```

Comment: Your suggested pattern is way too different from OP's. Why do you think it should help?

Comment: It solves the problem `I am trying to replace Hyphen, space and questionmarks with * using a regular expression in Coldfusion` and I explained why I think that's a better way to write it.

Comment: So, that is why you added an exclamation mark? OP's regex shows an attempt to only match the symbols in a *sequence*, yours does not, your regex will replace a hyphen in compound words. It will corrupt the string, not help.

Comment: You may be right that they do want to do it in sequence. I attempted to answer the question, rather than look at the reg exp example the OP gave as they say it doesn't work. As for the `!` - I misread the part - will update my answer.